# In matlab how do I change the column and row markers in a heatmap

Tags: matlab, plot, heatmap

I have some data that's stored in a 10x11 double. I would like for these labels on the x axis to be multiplied by 30000 and to start at 0 while I want the labels on the y axis to start and 1 and be scaled with 1. 
So let's say that we have the following:

```
a=rand(10,11);
heatmap(a)
```

Which generates the following heatmap

[image: heatmap]

I would like the x axis to be labelled as 0,30000,60000.... and the y axis to remain as is. Anybody know how to do that?

I also want to label both axes with some kind of name (say var1 and var2).

This is in Matlab R2017a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of R2017b, you can use the `XDisplayLabels` property of the `heatmap` object

```
a=rand(10,11);
hm = heatmap(a);
% Change x axis tick labels to some array
% hm.XDisplayLabels = [0:3e4:(numel(hm.XDisplayLabels)-1)*3e4];
% Change x axis tick labels to the current labels * 3e4 (same result)
hm.XDisplayLabels = str2double(hm.XDisplayData)*3e4 - 3e4;

% To add axes labels to *most* chart types in MATLAB, use `XLabel` and `YLabel` properties
hm.XLabel = 'var2';
hm.YLabel = 'var1';
```

Output:

[image: heatmap]

The `heatmap` object introduced in R2017a has many more options in R2017b, namely `XDisplayLabels` doesn't exist in R2017a! You might be better off using the legacy (R2009b - present) `HeatMap` object (note the case-sensitivity here). It's less pretty but more customisable...

```
% Create legacy heatmap
hm = HeatMap(a);
hm.Colormap = bone; % Change colours
% Add y and x tick labels
hm.RowLabels = 10:-1:1;
hm.ColumnLabels = (0:10)*3e4;
% Slant the labels
hm.ColumnLabelsRotate = 50;

% This HeatMap is one of the few plots without XLabel and YLabel! 
% use addXLabel and addYLabel instead
hm.addXLabel('var2');
hm.addYLabel('var1');
```

Output:

[image: plot2]

Comment: hm.XDisplayLabels = str2double(hm.XDisplayData)*3e4 - 3e4;
 gives an error but hm.XLabel = 'number of images';
hm.YLabel = 'colour consistency weight'; do work. if I remove the xdisplaylabels line.

Comment: Thanks that explain it.

Comment: No worries, between it being a new feature which has changed quite a bit and the very similar naming to the old function, I'm not surprised there's some confusion!